# Regex in PHP not working as expected

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

I am using this regex `^([\S\s]{50,400}[\.\!\?])(?:\s|)[A-Z]`which works fine in [regexr.com](http://regexr.com/) and [regex101](https://regex101.com/). Also it works quite good on my websites, just with in a few cases it doesnt catch the the text I want to. It happens that sometimes the code gets far more than the wanted text, but it works on the mentioned websites. Anyone has an idea why does this happen? Here y php code:

```
preg_match('/^([\S\s]{50,400}[\.\!\?])(?:\s|)[^\s]/', $descr, $matches);
if(isset($matches[1]))$descr = $matches[1];
```

Also here one of the cases where my regex doesnt work (in my php code):

> Dieses Luxus-Apartmentanlage liegt nur 50 m vom Strand entfernt und in 5/10 Minuten sind zu Fuß der reizvolle traditionelle Fischerhafen von Cala Bona sowie die Strände von Cala Bona und Port Verd zu erreichen. Die Anlage besteht aus zwei Gebäuden mit je sechs Wohnungen, durch einen gemeinsamen Zugangsbereich miteinander verbunden. Die Gebäude sind mit einem Aufzug für den bequemen Zugang von der Tiefgarage ausgestattet. Es stehen zwei oder drei Zimmer-Wohnungen, mit einer Gesamtwohnfläche von 80 m2 bis 85 m2 zur Verfügung Die Wohnungen im Erdgeschoss profitieren von privaten Gärten und grossen Terrassen. Die im ersten Stock gelegenen Wohnungen haben großzügige Terrassen und die vier Dachgeschosswohnungen verfügen über 50 m2 grosse Sonnenterrassen mit spektakulärem Blick auf das Meer und die Berge. Jede Wohnung bietet auch einen eigenen Parkplatz und Abstellraum für Fahrräder und Koffer etc. .. Die Anlage wurde von einem der renommiertesten Architekten entworfen , in einem traditionellen mediterranen Stil .

This is what should be catched:

> Dieses Luxus-Apartmentanlage liegt nur 50 m vom Strand entfernt und in 5/10 Minuten sind zu Fuß der reizvolle traditionelle Fischerhafen von Cala Bona sowie die Strände von Cala Bona und Port Verd zu erreichen. Die Anlage besteht aus zwei Gebäuden mit je sechs Wohnungen, durch einen gemeinsamen Zugangsbereich miteinander verbunden.

Maybe the code helps someone, if we get it to work 100% of the times :)

Comment: What is the expected capture for your example?

Comment: It works pretty fine for me. What problem do you have?

Comment: [It works with this text.](https://ideone.com/uAUs8A). However, I suspect you need to use `preg_match('/^([\S\s]{50,400}[.!?])\s?\S/u', $descr, $matches)` where the main idea is to use `u` modifier. The `\s?\S` (it is equal to `(?:\s|)[^\s]`) also seems redundant to me, but you may have a reason to use that pattern at the end.

Comment: Thanks @WiktorStribiżew . True that it works. I read the text out of a mysql database with utf8 encoding. I will check if there is some problem with the text I retrieve.

Comment: @timniko See my answer below.

Answer (score 0):

this code should work for you

```
$re = '/^([\S\s]{50,400}[\.\!\?])(?:\s[A-Z])/';
$str = 'Dieses Luxus-Apartmentanlage liegt nur 50 m vom Strand entfernt und in 5/10 Minuten sind zu Fuß der reizvolle traditionelle Fischerhafen von Cala Bona sowie die Strände von Cala Bona und Port Verd zu erreichen. Die Anlage besteht aus zwei Gebäuden mit je sechs Wohnungen, durch einen gemeinsamen Zugangsbereich miteinander verbunden. Die Gebäude sind mit einem Aufzug für den bequemen Zugang von der Tiefgarage ausgestattet. Es stehen zwei oder drei Zimmer-Wohnungen, mit einer Gesamtwohnfläche von 80 m2 bis 85 m2 zur Verfügung Die Wohnungen im Erdgeschoss profitieren von privaten Gärten und grossen Terrassen. Die im ersten Stock gelegenen Wohnungen haben großzügige Terrassen und die vier Dachgeschosswohnungen verfügen über 50 m2 grosse Sonnenterrassen mit spektakulärem Blick auf das Meer und die Berge. Jede Wohnung bietet auch einen eigenen Parkplatz und Abstellraum für Fahrräder und Koffer etc. .. Die Anlage wurde von einem der renommiertesten Architekten entworfen , in einem traditionellen mediterranen Stil .';

preg_match_all($re, $str, $matches, PREG_SET_ORDER, 0);

// Print the entire match result
var_dump($matches[0][1]);
```

it matches desired result in group 1. see result in [online compiler](https://ideone.com/CK7yKn)

or you can use the code

```
$re = '/^([\S\s]{50,400}[\.\!\?])(?:\s[A-Z])/';
$str = 'Dieses Luxus-Apartmentanlage liegt nur 50 m vom Strand entfernt und in 5/10 Minuten sind zu Fuß der reizvolle traditionelle Fischerhafen von Cala Bona sowie die Strände von Cala Bona und Port Verd zu erreichen. Die Anlage besteht aus zwei Gebäuden mit je sechs Wohnungen, durch einen gemeinsamen Zugangsbereich miteinander verbunden. Die Gebäude sind mit einem Aufzug für den bequemen Zugang von der Tiefgarage ausgestattet. Es stehen zwei oder drei Zimmer-Wohnungen, mit einer Gesamtwohnfläche von 80 m2 bis 85 m2 zur Verfügung Die Wohnungen im Erdgeschoss profitieren von privaten Gärten und grossen Terrassen. Die im ersten Stock gelegenen Wohnungen haben großzügige Terrassen und die vier Dachgeschosswohnungen verfügen über 50 m2 grosse Sonnenterrassen mit spektakulärem Blick auf das Meer und die Berge. Jede Wohnung bietet auch einen eigenen Parkplatz und Abstellraum für Fahrräder und Koffer etc. .. Die Anlage wurde von einem der renommiertesten Architekten entworfen , in einem traditionellen mediterranen Stil .';

preg_match($re, $str, $matches, PREG_OFFSET_CAPTURE, 0);

// Print the entire match result
var_dump($matches[1][0]);
```

see [online compiler](https://ideone.com/OYssJv)

Comment: Why using preg_match_all? How is it different from OP except you doesn't deall with punctuation not followed by space?

Comment: I changed the regex, added [A-Z] in the non capturing group

Comment: OK, but it doesn't change anything, `[A-Z]` wasn't inside the capture goup. You just doesn't match strings without a space after the punctuation, it's a regression.

Comment: Thanks @marvel308 for your try, but the result is still the same! I know that in online compliers it works, it also works for the majority of the properties on my website. Maybe some special characters are causing the problem? The code works fine with _just a few exceptions_, so the only thing that changes is the text.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I figured it out! The problem was caused by line breaks having a space before it. This works: `^([\S\s]{50,400}[\.\!\?])(?:\s?\s)[A-Z]`. The expression can surely be optimized, you may have some suggestions. Thank you all for the help!

Comment: It will not match a string that have exactly 400 character long (including punctuation).

Comment: You could use a lookahead and escapeis not mandatory in a character class. `^([\S\s]{50,400}[.!?])(?=\s*[A-Z]|$)`

Answer (score 0):

I have several things to note here.

- You deal with Unicode texts, and thus you really should consider using a `u` UNICODE modifier. It will enable 2 PCRE flags: it enables the PCRE engine to handle strings as UTF8 strings (by turning on `PCRE_UTF8` verb) and make the shorthand character classes in the pattern Unicode aware (by enabling `PCRE_UCP` verb).
- The `\s?\s[^\s]` and similar patterns you are using at the end of the pattern do not make much sense. The `(?:\s|)` pattern matches 1 single whitespace, 1 or 0 times (so, this whitespace is optional). The `[^\s]` matches any char but whitespace, so it is equal to `\S`. So, the end of the sentence must be followed with 1 or 0 spaces, and then a non-whitespace. Either remove `(?:\s?\s)[A-Z]`, or `(?:\s|)[^\s]`, or replace as @Toto has suggested, with a lookahead `(?=\s+\p{Lu}|$)` to make sure you also match the last sentence and other sentences that overlap with the pattern (if you are also using `m` modifier of course, since you have a `^` anchor in the pattern)
- You do not have to escape `!`, `?` and `.` inside a character class. They do not have a special meaning inside `[...]`.
- There is no need to use `[\s\S]` in PHP regex to match any char. You may use a mere `.` and pass the PCRE_DOTALL (`s`) modifier. This is a more native and straight-forward way to match any char in PHP regex.

So, I suggest

```
'/^.{50,400}[.!?](?=\s+\p{Lu}|$)/us'
```

**Details**

- `^` - start of string (or line if `m` modifier is passed)
- `.{50,400}` - any 50 to 400 chars as many as possible
- `[.!?]` - a `.`, `!` or `?` char
- `(?=\s+\p{Lu}|$)` - there must be 1+ whitespaces and any uppercase letter or end of string (or line if `m` modifier is passed) immediately to the right of the current location.

[PHP demo](https://ideone.com/fnB4nX):

```
preg_match('/^.{50,400}[.!?](?=\s+\p{Lu}|$)/us', $descr, $matches);
echo $matches[0];
// => Dieses Luxus-Apartmentanlage liegt nur 50 m vom Strand entfernt und in 5/10 Minuten sind zu Fuß der reizvolle traditionelle Fischerhafen von Cala Bona sowie die Strände von Cala Bona und Port Verd zu erreichen. Die Anlage besteht aus zwei Gebäuden mit je sechs Wohnungen, durch einen gemeinsamen Zugangsbereich miteinander verbunden.
```